# how to access fields with visible = "false" with jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, selector

I have this fields, with visible = "false" I can access it via the cs page in backend, but how can I acess this control with jquery?
I little code might help..

```
<tr>
  <td class="TDCaption" style="text-align: left">
    <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" ForeColor="#CC0000"></asp:Label>
    <div class="DivStyleWithScroll" style="width: 100%; overflow: scroll; height: 250px;">
      <asp:GridView ID="grdReport" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
      DataKeyNames="CustCode" ShowFooter="True" EmptyDataText="No record found"
      PageSize="50" CssClass="mGrid" onrowdatabound="grdReport_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="lblCustCodes" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CustCode") %>' CssClass="grdCustName"></asp:Label>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <%--other columns--%>
```

The jquery is

```
 $('#<%=btnCompare.ClientID%>').click(function () {
            if ($(':checkbox:checked').size() == 0) {
            }
            else {
                custList = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function () { return $(this).closest('tr').find('.grdCustName').text() }).get();
                alert(custList);
            }
    });
```

Comment: I think I'm right in thinking that `.Visible = false` will stop the control from being rendered in the HTML. Have you checked the HTML source sent to the browser?

Comment: @freefaller You're entirely right. Make that the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe setting `.Visible = false` will stop the control from being rendered into the HTML, so the jQuery will simple not be able tofind it.

Instead, for code-behind, try using...

```
ctrl.Style("display") = "none"
```

Or on the markup, try using the following attribute on the control...

```
style="display:none"
```

Answer (score 0):

If Visible is false, then the control did not go down to the client, so you cannot directly access it from javascript/jquery: it simply isn't there. you can put the control's value in some `hidden field` and then can access it. as they are never visible in frontend. `Hiddenfields` are visible only in `HTML` source.

Answer (score 0):

`Label.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent` in code behind

then set the Label `Visible` to `true`